# How can Flutter Widgets be sized relatively to each other?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm a couple days into learning Flutter, and I keep running into a situation where I want to scale a collection of widgets (aka a `Row`, `Column`, `Stack`, etc) down when the screen shrinks, akin to what `Flexible()` does. Except unlike `Flexible()`, I want *all* children to scale down when the container shrinks, not just the largest elements. Consider this example of a `Column()` (green) with two children: a red child matching its parent's width, and a blue child with half the parent's width:

[image]

In the above case, if the green `Column()` were to be constrained such that its width was less, you would end up with something like such:

[image]

However, what I am wanting is for each of the child elements (red/blue) to scale their width/height relative to each other, like this:

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

In the specific `Column()` case I illustrated above, my workaround was to add a `Row()` containing the blue widget as well as a `Padding()`, both with equal flex properties, so that when the `Column()` shrunk the blue element scaled correctly. I feel like this is a hack though, and wouldn't be as feasible if I had many elements with differing widths/alignments. It would be a nightmare to add one `Padding()` for left/right aligned elements and two for centered ones. Is there a better way?

I'd also like to know of a similar solution for using `Stack()`s. Using the `Positional()` element seems to set the width/height in a way that the `Stack()` crops any overflow. It'd be nice to have a `Stack()` that scales all its children the same, just like if it was a single image, and similar to my `Column()` example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [FractionallySizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html) class, you can specify the widthFactor and heightFactor e.g. 0.5 so that it is always half the size of the parent container.

Example:

```
  Flexible(
            child: FractionallySizedBox(
              widthFactor: 0.5,
              heightFactor: 0.5,
              alignment: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Might you have any ideas on how to make this work with a `Stack()`?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Thanks for your help!